# How do I show data for 4 weeks on a Google Sheets chart by week day?

Tags: google-sheets, charts, excel-charts, google-sheets-charts

I want to show data for 4 weeks on a Google Sheets chart.

I have tried to do this and it is mostly ok as this is correct:

1. The X-axis shows the days of the week
2. The Y-axis is the weight number

Issues I have with my current implementation are:

1. I had to make a separate series for each week when I wanted it automatically group the data by week number. (I then can't name each series)
2. The data is off by one day. Monday's data doesn't show which means Tuesday's data is showing in place of Monday and so on.

Here is a link to the google sheet and a screenshot below: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/147RMW2JE7MoWz53EZuB-nHj-p_xeKez_ze_0mqq8NGA/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

My expected result would look more like this:
[image]

Here the lines are shown grouped by each week AND data is shown for each day

Comment: Can you somehow show us your expected results? Even if it's only a rough drawing by hand... Because we can now see what you've tried but not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @a-burge hi I've edited it and added a picture for what my expected results are. Does this make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are missing the first day of every week is that you have checked the *Use row 1 as heeaders* so every series will remove the first datapoint (monday in your case) and insert it as the label for that series (you can see that in the legend).

If you uncheck that checkbox and change your range for the X-axis so it goes from Monday to Sunday you get the correct graph.

[image: Sheet without legend]

The problem with the previous graph is that although all its datapoints are correct there is no legend. But unfortunately there is no way to insert a legend easily because you cannot go and change this manually, the label for each series has to come from the cells.

What you can do to work around this limitation is change your data so the label for each series sits on top of your data and keep the *Use row `x` as headers* checked:

[image: Example with label]

Of course this is not the only solution, you can go on multiple ways here, copy the table in a single sheet for every week, or just live without labels. Stack the weeks horizontally so everyone has its week number on top of the weight column, etc

Comment: If you're willing to accept Sundays as the first day of a week (rather than Monday), you can restructure your data using this function and then chart on that (use an open range to include future weeks): `=QUERY(A1:D29,"select dayOfWeek(B),sum(D) group by dayOfWeek(B) pivot A label dayOfWeek(B) 'Day (Sunday = 1)'",1)`

Comment: Can you feed formulas directly to the graph or do you need to first put it somewhere inside the sheet and after that import it? 
Cool suggestion either way.

Comment: @Raserhin, you use this somewhere in the sheet to re-format the output to better suit the charting.